# Creating / Displaying Array Results with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins, rss

I'm currently working on a web app and using jGFeed to pull in an RSS feed from my blog.  (Eventually, I'll be pulling in jQTouch to build the UI.)  I'm able to grab the content I need, now I just need to do the next step.

What I need to do is, first, display a list of links.  These links are the titles of each entry.  When a user clicks on this link, the content for this particular entry is displayed for the user to read.

I don't have a ton of experience doing this, so I'm proud to have gotten to this point.  But now I need to take it to the next level and could use some guidance on working with arrays and getting this to work within jQuery.  Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>TEST APP</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jgfeed-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.jGFeed('http://feeds.feedburner.com/solidverbal/clickchorus/app', function(feeds){
        // Check for errors
        if(!feeds){
        // there was an error
        return false;
        }
        // do whatever you want with feeds here
        var title = "";
        var content = "";
        for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
            var entry = feeds.entries[i];
            // Entry title
            title = title + "<li id=\"title\"" + i + ">" + entry.title + "</li>";
            // Entry content
            content = content + "<li id=\"content\"" + i + ">" + entry.content + "</li>";
        }
        $("#results_titles").html("<ul>" + title + "</ul>");
        $("#results_content").html("<ul>" + content + "</ul>");

    }, 10);
});
</script>

</head> 
<body> 

<div id="results_titles">LOADING</div>
<div id="results_content">LOADING</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what problem you need help with. Can you be more specific about what needs to happen next, or needs fixing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand, you want to stock those feeds.entries in an array even if they already are in an array.  feeds.entries is the array you want. So feeds.entries[0].title is the title you need and feeds.entries[0].content the content.  Try doing something like this:

```
//Create the <ul><li><a></a></li></ul> structure links
var sAnchors='<ul>';
for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
   var sAnchors += "<li><a href='#link' id='title_"+i+"' class='giveFeeds'>feeds.entries[i].title</a></li>";
}
sAnchors += '</ul>';

//Append the <a>.
$('#results_titles').append(sAnchors);

//When the user clicks on the giveFeeds link....
$('.giveFeeds').live('click', function(e) {
//Get the feed number
var tmpId = $(e.target).attr('id');
//Returns the value after the '_' char and make sure it returns de number.
var id = parseInt(tmpId.split('_')[1]);
//Use the id value to get the desired feed
var wantedFeed = feeds.entries[id].content;
//Then do whatever you want with that entry
... 
});
```

You might get some problems with vars such as feeds.entries since you want it to be global.  I suggest you append all the feeds in seperates  in the "for" loop (sDivs = '"+feeds.entries[i].content+"";).  Like this, you'll only have to use the id var (var id = parseInt(...)) to know what  you wanna show ($('#content'+id).show()).  Finally, you might wanna choose to add some animation to make this more interesting (slideUp, slideDown, animate) look out these methods over the net.

Comment: By the way, this is not tested.  I assume you can debug whatever mistakes i could have done.

Comment: I played around with this... it's absolutely perfect!  Thanks so much.